# Could someone translate this poster for me?

Tags: translation, meaning

I've had a few friends take a look and they had very differing opinions.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Chinese Language Stack Exchange. Could you please add some information about the object in the image? This would at least provide some context.

Comment: First, it's Japanese. It's a really cool graphic, but you should be asking Japanese stack exchange. Please understand I'm not being picky, if I could read it I would tell you what I think. It's so beautiful I'd love to know the answer. The big black characters say "Don't change" or "It's not easy" but I could be wrong on that because it's Japanese. Japanese has a certain curviness to its characters, for your future reference. You can see that here in the smaller characters. If you find out please post the answer, I love the artwork!

Comment: If you had posted a full pic, it would make us easier to get the originals. Since "404" is a key clue to get.

Answer (score 2):

the picture is part of a bigger poster of 狗神樂隊 (a rock & roll band) in shanghai, their web site is here:

https://goushen.bandcamp.com/album/-

the three big black character is "不易滚". two small red characters in the "seal" is "狗" (dog) and an inverted "神" (god).

滚 (u+6eda) is a variant character of 滾 (u+6efe)

rock & roll in chinese is 搖**滾**樂.

need more elaboration?

Comment: 不易= not easy (hard); (搖)滾= (rock) & roll-- 不易滾 =不易搖滾 = 'Hard Rock!'

Comment: 狗神 in English is 'dog god' this name spells the same from either end.  With the character 神 inverted, I think their true band name should be 'dog dog' (狗狗) which means 'doggie' in English

Comment: yes, hard rock :) the dog & inverted god, or vice versa; ought to have a hidden meaning. i'm tired at this moment, need more time to "think" :(

Comment: You can add these info into your answer to make it perfect.

Comment: maybe later :) btw, i'm "shocked" to read the first answer, claiming that's japanese. then the second one say it doesn't make sense. am i too old, and isolated from the real?

Comment: I believe it's “不易滚“ rather than “不易滾” 滚 is not a variants of 滾. It's only because one is simplified Chinese and the other one is traditional Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense.

The 3 black words mean
不 = No
易 = Easy
滚 = Fuck off

The words inside the box
狗神=Dog God

and the small black words are the name of the author and the picture created date.

Comment: 不易滚 is only a album's name. That's why it doesn't make sense since.